# How to fetch data from "Many to many" relationship table? JPA +SPRINGBOOT

Tags: java, sql, jpa, many-to-many

I am wondering how to fetch the data from many to many relationship table that was autogenerated with JPA?

[Database design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSCfh.png)

I wrote some query code that gives me exactly the data I would like to fetch. Although I am not sure how to translate it to the JPA:

```
SELECT id, first_name, last_name, phone_number, shift_id FROM 
FROM users
RIGHT JOIN employees_enrolled
ON users.id = employees_enrolled.employee_id
```

Employee extends User.

User model:

```
    @Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
```

Employee model:

```
@Entity(name = "employee")
public class Employee extends User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6529685098267757690L;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "enrolledEmployees")
    private List<Shift> shifts = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false)
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "hours", nullable = false)
    private double hours;


    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(long id)
    {
        super(id);
    }

    public Employee(long id, String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName,
                    String email, String phoneNumber, String authLevel, String address, double hours) {
        super(id, username, password, firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber, authLevel);
        this.address = address;
        this.hours = hours;
    }
```

Shift model:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "shift")
    public class Shift implements Serializable {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7065683873804696266L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
    
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(
        name = "employees_enrolled",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "shift_id", referencedColumnName = "id", 
        insertable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", 
        referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
        private List<Employee> enrolledEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
    
    
        private Long employee_id; 
    
        @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
        private String description;
    
        @Column(name = "address", nullable = false)
        private String address;
```

Comment: See example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72162260/query-many-to-many-jpa/72163101#72163101